# Insert several nan values after every element of an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, insert, nan

I am trying to do something very simple, but I am stuck. Some help would be very nice.
I have this:

```
x=([0.,1.,2.,3.,4.])
```

and I want to obtain this:

```
x1=([0.,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,1.,nan,,nan,nan,nan,nan,2.,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,3.,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,4.,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan])
```

5 nan values after every element of this array.
My attempt so far:

```
x = np.arange(0,5, dtype=float)
x1= np.insert(x,[i+1 for i in x], np.nan)
```

but I can only obtain this:

```
array([ 0., nan,  1., nan,  2., nan,  3., nan,  4., nan])
```

And trying to do it again I got a bound error.
Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add lists using infix `+` and also `sum` (with a starting value of `[]`).
This means you can do it like this:

```py
y = sum([[a] + [nan] * 5 for a in x],[])
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a full `nan` array and insert the `x` values with slice:

```
y = np.full(len(x)*6, np.nan)
y[::6] = x
```

Output (`y`):

```
array([ 0., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  1., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  2.,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  3., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  4., nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan])
```